# Is it possible to create clickable links to macos mail.app email via "message://..." in orgmode?

Tags: org-mode, email

I use the "Copy Message URL" quite heavily in mail app. I would like to paste the link into an org document and make it a clickable link that opens the email in mail.app. This does not currently work. I did try:

```
[[message://...][email link]]
```

But this did not work.

Comment: Have you read `(info "(org) Adding hyperlink types")` in the Org Mode manual?

Comment: I assume you can either call mail.app from the commandline with a message://... argument, or else you can use AppleScript to open the message URL.

Comment: Yes, I did look, but do not know elisp and how to transform the org-man.el into one that will resolve links to mail app.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
(require 'org)
(org-add-link-type "message"
 (lambda (id)
  (shell-command
   (concat "open message:" id))))
```

The link should be in the following format:

```
[[message:<message_id@domain.com>][Apple Mail Link]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Lars Careliusson's answer, I made it work by doing the following:

When 'Copy Message URL', append `%3c` and `%3e` before and after messageid, as suggested by [this article](https://thesweetsetup.com/working-email-urls-macos/). Here is the Applescript from the article:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set selectedMessages to selection
    set theMessage to item 1 of selectedMessages
    set messageid to message id of theMessage
    -- Make URL (must use URL-encoded values for "<" and ">")
    set urlText to "message://" & "%3c" & messageid & "%3e"
    return urlText
end tell
```

Then, add this to your emacs init file:

```
(org-add-link-type "message"
 (lambda (id)
  (shell-command
   (concat "open message:" id))))
```

and the link should be in the following format:

```
[[<copied_text_from_apple_script>][Subject]]
```

Alternatively, you can wrap `%3c` and `%3e` into the `org-add-link-type` function and paste the Message ID directly into the org file.